# Curious about an old algorithm which calculates modular inverse

Tags: algorithm-analysis, correctness-proof, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am not sure if I should ask this question here or somewhere else. In fact, I initially asked my question [here at mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256906/curious-about-an-old-algorithm-which-calculates-modular-inverse) but it was marked as off-topic

**Background**: I was searching through random mathematics paper that are related to cryptography and I came across [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01175v1.pdf) (page 3). I just read the abstract and algorithm itself, I don't understand Chinese. It offers new method to find a Modular inverses. It has some interesting properties that I observed:

1. during each step iteration of the loop: $x_{11} * x_{22} + x_{12} * x_{21} = m$ which is good to validate the result during each iteration
2. algorithm terminates in even number of steps for some unknown reason

In abstract section, author says this method was invented by [this mathematicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_Jiushao).

My question is, why does this algorithm always terminate in aeven number of steps (or number of iterations of the loop is always even)?

**Algorithm** to calculate: $a^{-1} (\bmod m)$:

> $\text{xgcd}(a, m):$
>
> $\quad x_{11} \leftarrow 1, x_{21} \leftarrow 0, x_{12} \leftarrow a, x_{22} \leftarrow m$
>
> $\quad \text{While }(x_{12} > 1) \text{ do}$
>
> $\quad \quad \text{If }(x_{22} > x_{12}) \text{ then}$
>
> $\quad\quad\quad\quad q \leftarrow \Big\lfloor\frac{x_{22} - 1}{x_{12}}\Big\rfloor$
>
> $\quad\quad\quad\quad r \leftarrow x_{22} - q ~x_{12}$
>
> $\quad\quad\quad\quad \begin{pmatrix}x_{11} & x_{12}\\x_{21} & x_{22}\end{pmatrix} \leftarrow \begin{pmatrix}x_{11} & x_{12}\\q~x_{11} + x_{21} & r\end{pmatrix} $
>
> $\quad\quad \text{If }(x_{12} > x_{22}) \text{ then}$
>
> $\quad\quad\quad\quad q \leftarrow \Big\lfloor\frac{x_{12} - 1}{x_{22}}\Big\rfloor$
>
> $\quad\quad\quad\quad r \leftarrow x_{12} - q~x_{22}$
>
> $\quad\quad\quad\quad \begin{pmatrix}x_{11} & x_{12}\\x_{21} & x_{22}\end{pmatrix} \leftarrow \begin{pmatrix}q~x_{21} + x_{11} & r\\x_{21} & x_{22}\end{pmatrix}$
>
> $\quad \text{Return } x_{11}$

- [**Screenshot** of the algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWFk8.png)
- [**Python**](https://goo.gl/SvreH4) and [**SageMath**](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFVNtugkAQfTfxH0YbIiimzvKkqT72C_rYxGBZlISLLtD6-d3ZgbKCpJsYJ3Pmcmb2LJGM4Xg_f0Vu6EPmQyRP9Xn_Hqal9HbTCeiTxNDiHsz2gFAoyItKG28Q6l_WBNK5qiSvYCGVKtRs0fmVrGqVw3q73bJT6g5W3v2ICFQbXoxtI4KQDSPiAUGhkbDJEQ85hGRNjoV0lh7LDGuRoFNW8lpSP3Z34M8lSSX3PAD2skaKWRuhoXbglL4ZorVQ_PnIinwoL0WdRnCS8KFqSegCPodV6TjgUlWuyNW4kq5SKYPBknex6i2od5bNlvXKPG8Y1e6E_1eg72Awvmlz4JGGFW46O06LQrmuCVwDevBqop_0Uzq6CbsZbkR9GNYoowlBM6StDyuO1KD6NWRqeCPzFv_yRou3GOeNHW8xwhs73oJ541PeOOA9IjQW2fw7TJNIv7WyTisWVl5nJ6mgiPnyyDkn4RiFhO3mHP1U9OWjx8rhe3ZAkHNDihg8ZGY8nXBj_oJgoJUngiBoPyOkYO8XvMTvXQ==&lang=sage) implementations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace:

$$ ~~q \leftarrow \Big\lfloor\frac{a - 1}{b}\Big\rfloor $$
$$ r \leftarrow a - q ~b  $$

By $q, r \leftarrow \text{divmod}(a, ~ b)$

> Algorithm terminates in even number of steps for some unknown reason

Those matrices assignments seem to be a fancy way of writing:

$$ \gcd(m_0, \color{blue}{a_0}) = \gcd(a_0, \color{red}{m_0 \pmod{a_0}}) = \gcd(\color{red}{m_1}, \color{blue}{\underbrace{a_0 \pmod{m_1}}_{a_1}}) = \dots = \gcd(m_n, 1)$$

So $a_i$ decreases every $2$ iterations, and $\gcd$ stops when $a_n = 1$.

Of course, you're not interested in computing the $\gcd$ per see, since you already know it's $1$, but finding the integers such that $Xm + Ya = gcd(m, a) = 1$.

Comment: So, I get this is not a "new" algorithm, but rephrasing the one that is usually attributed to Euclid? (Ah: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Historical_development) mentions the same name as linked in the question)

Comment: @HendrikJan, I don't get what you're asking... (sometimes my English fails me). But OP's algorithm is finding the modular inverse of $a \mod{m}$, which can be computed using [the Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation) to solve $ax + by = \gcd(a,b)$, but I'm not sure who came up with it first.

Comment: According to wikipedia Euclid's algorithm was probably known before Euclid (300BC) and Qin Jiushao is around 1200. I was just asking for an explicit confirmation that these algorithms were similar. But I think you answered that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you replace that second `if` with `else if`, the explanation of an even number of iterations is simple; you are repeatedly computing remainders, so each iteration swaps which of $x_{12}$ and $x_{22}$ is bigger. Each iteration alternately decreases $x_{12}$ or $x_{22}$ starting with $x_{22}$. Since the loop ends after decreasing $x_{12}$, you must go through an even number of iterations.